# What's the best method to predict/generate signal from one sensor (source) to signal from another another (target)?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, sequence-modeling, machine-translation, signal-processing

I was wondering what is the best method out there to find relationship between two 1D signals so that I can predict/generate one (source) from the other (target). For example, let's say that in response to an event, my sensor A's readings vary in a certain way for 5 seconds. For the same event sensor B's readings vary as well for 5 seconds. Sensor A and B are not measuring the same physical quantities but respond to the same event and seem to have a relationship.

What can I do to use the signal from sensor A to learn how the signal from sensor B would look like for that event? What is the state of the art in deep learning?